# Executing code from a textbox on the fly

Tags: c#

I have a service that has a lot of different methods with a lot of parameters. I have created a service client but it would be quite a pain to create UI for all of the possible parameters and functions so I have just one button per method and the code configures all the parameters. It works well, but every time you need another parameter, you have to change code. So I thought that if I had the textbox with code that will be compiled and called on the fly that would be quite handy to use. So what I want is that I have a textbox that has code like `ExecuteOperation1("a", "b", "c")` where ExecuteOperation is defined in my form class. And then I can change parameters on the fly easily. I tried to search how it can be done but all examples show compilation with namespaces and classes and so on. Is there a way to kind of run dynamic code inside your class somehow. Another simple solutions for my problem are appreciated as well of course.

Comment: Are you sure it's [tag:code-generation] instead of [tag:reflection]?

Comment: Check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12499/Run-Time-Code-Generation-I-Compile-C-Code-using-Mi

Comment: @J.A.I.L. Not quite sure really, it's not either I guess, may be it's better to remove the tag at all.

Comment: Sounds like you want to build a UI based on reflecting the parameter values from each method in your service. Pretty simple using `GetType()/typeof(X)` and `GetMethods()`, though you have to ensure that you handle building the right input box for each parameter type which means you are limited to whatever param types you code for. Complex types would be off-limits unless you created UCs to represent their values/structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways of running code on the fly. One nice way is to use the Microsoft-provided file dynamic.cs available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx) (under LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery). An example of use is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99787709-1a3e-436e-bb4b-e2c11feca968/evaluate-string-into-mathematical-expression).

You can also build expression trees manually yourself as per [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). But you'd need to write some parsing code to do this.

I have used both of the above, and I think that the first approach seems the most promising for the problem you want to solve. You can, for example, make some arbitrary object `o` a parameter of your expression, and include other objects too such as `settings`, so the user can write, `o.ExecuteOperation1("a", "b", "c", settings)`, as in the test program below.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

// ...

public class Settings
{
    public int x;
}

public class Window
{
    public object ExecuteOperation1(string a, string b, string c, Settings s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", a, b, c, s.x);
        return true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strExpr = "o.ExecuteOperation1(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\", settings)";
        Window form = new Window();
        Settings s = new Settings();
        s.x = 42;

        Type retType = typeof(object);
        ParameterExpression[] paramExprs = new ParameterExpression[] { 
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(Window), "o"), 
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(Settings), "settings") };
        LambdaExpression Le = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(
            paramExprs, retType, strExpr);
        Delegate compiledLe = Le.Compile();

        object result = compiledLe.DynamicInvoke(form, s);
        Console.WriteLine("Result is {0}", result.ToString());
    }
}
```

This program outputs

```
a, b, c, 42
Result is True
```

I had to comment out lines 1137 to 1138 in Dynamic.cs to get this to work (these lines preclude the use of the user-defined type `Window`).

Finally, there is [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn), which makes the .net compiler available as a service. I haven't used this myself, because it's in tech preview and I wanted something I could deploy now. Nevertheless it seems to come with plenty of examples, some geared towards that kind of thing you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my parameters are really objects that I have to fill and the to pass to the method. So instead of just string "a" it has to be a var settings = new Settings {\*values are set here*\} that is further passed to the method. Is it possible for to write in the expression as well?

Comment: I think you need to play around with it to see what you can do. I would probably define the settings object(s) in a separate part of your form and then let the user specify it (them) as part of the string they type in. I've modified my answer to show this.

Comment: The most important part was to have this settings code from textbox, so this won't work like in your example. But I will try to see if I can modify it to do what I want. Perhaps we can do the same trick with settings and return them as separate expression but all that would make this thing quite complicated and I wanted to have just one textbox with all the code for the operation: creating object parameters, calling a method with these parameters.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik How about adding a method on the `Window` class to create your settings objects (or on a different factory class if you like but you'd have to pass that in as a parameter). E.g. on the `Window` class, `public Settings NewSettings(int _x) { return new Settings() { x = _x }; }`? The user can then write something like "`o.ExecuteOperation1("a", "b", "c", o.NewSettings(101))`". I tried this and it worked as expected.

Comment: That's what I though would work as well. Though this approach will require a lot of additional code and things will get more comples when there are more parameters and such. But thank you anyway for the reply, I will see if I can generalize something in an easy way like that. I was expecting there was a simple way that will just "magically" execute the code as if it was written directly in you source code file:)

Answer (score 0):

If it always looks like `ExecuteOperation1("a", "b", "c")` then you can use reflection to determine method and parameter names. For example the folloring code gives you a list of methods. MethodInfo.Invoke can be used to call the methods.

```
typeof(Service).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This is approach is not very flexible, but is relatively easy to understand and requires no additional libs.

Comment: It's not exactly "a", "b", "c", it was just a simplification not to go into details. I have few complex object parameters that I pass in so I am not sure it will be possible to use it like that. The most interesting part for me is to fill properties of these objects properly